# Can I test my apps on a first generation iPod Touch using Xcode 4?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode4, ipod-touch

Hi I have an app that supports iOS 3 however I've only ever tested it on an iPhone 4 (very bad practice I know). Lately in my updates people have been emailing me that my app is crashing on their older device, still running iOS 3. I am clearly including features only available in iOS 4 SDK but I can't find where they are in my code.

So to fix this I bought a first generation iPod touch from ebay (which I haven't received yet). Will I be able to build and run my app on this iPod touch or do I need to locate an older version of Xcode and the iPhone sdk (i.e Xcode 3.2.2) and build it using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't used any iOS 4+ specific APIs, you can test your apps on the iPod touch using Xcode 4.